# Shell script over some files

Tags: shell, solaris

I have to do some things in some files from a directory in solaris. In that directory, I have thousands of files. Some of them, begin with FAC_. I need to make an array variable with those names of files (which four first letters name are FAC_), and then go over the array to do some task to each file.

How can I accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest approach would be something like this:

```
files="FAC_*"

for file in $files; do
 echo "$file"
done
```

If the files aren't in the same directory as the script you can use the following line to retrieve them.

```
files="$path/FAC_*"
```

Comment: I have tried files=FAC_*.TXT and it doesn't work. I forgot to mention that the extension of the files I want to consider is TXT. Maybe the " before and after? I will try files="FAC_*.TXT"

Comment: You don't get any files or you get the wrong ones? Are the files in the same directory as the script you're launching?

Comment: I have tested and it doesn't work. I get a variable with value "FAC_*.TXT". As there is no such file, the script gives an error telling that file doesn't exists.

Comment: Can you find the files with `ls`? Solaris is case-sensitive, do you want `FAC_*.txt`?The wildcard in Unix is including extensions, so `FAC_*` should show the .txt files (and possible others).